# Конфликт размера операндов

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер

нужно значение из регистра edx перенести в массив символов. Не знаю как исправить конфликт операндов.

```
int main() {
    char buffer[5];
    int number = 255;
    int divider = 10;
    __asm {
        mov edx, 0
        mov eax, number
        mov ebx, divider
        div ebx
        add ebx, 48


        mov buffer[0], edx
    }
    cout << buffer << endl;
}
```

Comment: Не стоит использовать ассемблерные вставки.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте проще:

```
int main() 
{
    int b;
    int number = 255;
    int divider = 10;
    __asm {
        mov edx, 0
        mov eax, number
        mov ebx, divider
        div ebx

        mov b, edx
    }
    cout << b << endl;
}
```

Благо `cout` сам сумеет `int` вывести, ему не надо в строку его превращать...

Answer (score 1):

Здесь вы в однобайтовую ячейку пытаетесь положить значение из четырехбайтового регистра, из-за этого возникает конфликт размера операнда:

```
mov buffer[0], edx
```

Вам нужен только младший байт из регистра `edx`, т.е. регистр `dl`:

```
mov buffer[0], dl
```

Также у вас ошибка в логике программы: нужно добавлять 48 (код символа `'0'`) не к `ebx`, а к `edx` (или к `dl`).

Comment: И что потом будет выведено в `cout << buffer << endl;`? Ой, не того хочет ТС, не того... По-моему, он его в строку преобразовать хочет...

Comment: Да, вы правы я хочу преобразовать все это в строку.

Comment: @Harry, будет выведена цифра и мусор после нее. Понятно, что преобразовать в строку. Понятно что C++ и сам это может сделать, но может задание преобразовать число в символ средствами ассемблера.

Comment: Не цифра! Чтобы была цифра - надо к dl добавить 48...

Comment: @Harry дополнил ответ.